# Like operator is not working to retrieve only one value in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

This is my code

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "hostel";

// Create connection
$link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $state=$_POST['state'];
    $district=$_POST['district'];
    $area=$_POST['area'];
    $category=$_POST['hostel_category'];
    $bed=$_POST['bed_type'];
    $query_sid="SELECT * FROM hostel_register WHERE bed_type like '%".$bed."%' and state like '%".$state."%' and district like '%".$district."%' and category like '%".$category."%'  and status like '%".paid."%' and area like '%".$area."%'";
    if($result_sid = mysqli_query($link, $query_sid) ){


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sid)) {
    ?>
<center>

  <div class="col-sm-4 well"><h3><font color="#990000"><?php echo $row['hostel_name'];?></font></h3>
                        <p><p><?php echo $row['district'];?>-<?php echo $row['state'];?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $row['area'];?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $row['category'];?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $row['bed_type'];?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $row['rent_nonac_five'];?>/- Rs</p>
                        <p><a href="HostelDetails.php?details_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-info">Details</a></p>
  </div>

  </center>

     <?php   }

    /* free result set */
}
else {echo "No Result";}
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

In the DB there is a column "bed_type" with the value "AC Two Bed, AC Three Bed". Sorry I am writing full code but I am really confused. How to show only one value. I used "like" but this is fetching all values. But I want to show only one.

Comment: by `fetching all values`, do you mean it fetches "AC Two Bed, AC Three Bed" but you want only "AC Two Bed"?

Comment: Yes, I want to fetch any one

Comment: But in both there are AC so the Like operator fetching both.

Comment: you need to **normalize** your DB. **never** store multiple values in one column. I'm gonna write an answer explaining where you went wrong.

Comment: You need to escape $bed to prevent SQL injection! Even better use PDO.

Comment: you can do use explode() after fetching results from db

Comment: I think I explained it enough in my answer, but I want to point out that `so the Like operator fetching both` is not correct. Because there is no 'both'. There is only **one** value, which is `AC Two Bed, AC Three Bed`. Your DB does not interpret a comma as a separator between values, or else storing complex sentences as strings would be a nightmare. A comma is just another Character in your string.

Comment: @D.Rudra You creating Object of mysqli (new mysqli) and using procedural mysqli. variable $conn is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

you need to **normalize** your DB. **never** store multiple values in one column.

Storing multiple, comma separated values in a single column is never a good idea, one reason for that is because it leads to problems exactly like yours. (there are more reasons).
Obviously you are allowed to store Strings with commas, but your DB does not see "AC One Bed, AC Two Bed" as two different items, it is just **one** String.

And of yourse you also should not create another column called bed_type_2 because what if there is a third bed type?

So what you need to do in order to normalize your DB is this:

---

1) create a new table called `bed_types` with an id and a type / name

2) insert all possible bed types. One entry per type. (one for "AC Two Bed" and one for "AC Three Bed" etc.)

3) create another table called `hostel_register_bed_types`, which will function as a junctiontable / helpertable / jointable.
In that table, there is going to be a foreign key to the hostel_register_id and a foreign key to the bed_type_id.

---

If a hostel_register has multiple bed_types, you will insert a record into `hostel_register_bed_types` **for each bed type** that the hostel_register has.

Now you should have a more normalized Database structure and your bed types can be accessed/selected individually. A hostel_register can now have any amount of bed types, without storing multiple values in one column.

You will have to edit your query accordingly with join statements.

If you want to read up on these things, here are some links:
[Many-to-Many relationships and junction tables](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218734758-A-beginner-s-guide-to-many-to-many-relationships#junction)
[DB normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)